# Push list under a div

Tags: html, css, layout

I've got an annoying issue, if someone needs additional information please say, as I'm not sure what I should put up here to make the question clearer! In the first picture I have the current layout, I wanted to move the star ratings to below the pictures in the dashed div of the other users.

But when I do it , everything gets fugly, as you can see in the second picture. Does anyone know what I should be looking at to ensure the stars end up below the div with pictures of hte images. I've put my css at the bottom.

[image]

[image]

```
#gallery {  margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto; background:#EEE; float: left;  border:  width: 500px; solid  1px  #BBBBBB ; border-style: dashed; } * html #gallery { height: 12em; } /* IE6 */
.gallery.custom-state-active { background: #eee; }
.gallery li { float: left; width: 96px; height:86px  padding: 0.4em; margin: 0.4em 0.4em 0.4em 0.4em; text-align: center; }
.gallery li h5 { margin: 0 0 0.4em; cursor: move; }
.gallery li a { float: right; }
```

Comment: please show us your HTML

Comment: you can dump it here or post in in something like jsfiddle.net

Comment: ADded here http://pastebin.com/LLt172qa

Comment: I want the grid to be above and outside the div with the grey-ish background with the dashed border.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You closed part of a tag before you gave it the style attribute, shown as below:

```
<li class='current-rating'> style='width:105px;' Currently 3.5/5 Stars.</li>
```

Should be:

```
<li class='current-rating' style='width:105px;'> Currently 3.5/5 Stars.</li>
```

---

Forgot to close the `<h4>` tag:

```
<h4>Megan Fox was recommended because the following people also liked it
            <ol id='gallery' class='gallery ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix'>
            ...
```

Which should be:

```
<h4>Megan Fox was recommended because the following people also liked it</h4>
            <ol id='gallery' class='gallery ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix'>
            ...
```

---

```
border:  width: 500px; solid  1px  #BBBBBB ;
```

Should be:

```
width: 500px; 
border: 1px solid #BBBBBB;
```

---

```
height:86px  padding: 0.4em; margin: 0.4em 0.4em 0.4em 0.4em;
```

Should be:

```
height:86px;  padding: 0.4em; margin: 0.4em 0.4em 0.4em 0.4em;
```

---

Also, you currently have `<p id='initial p'>`
Note that you can only have one unique id in any page for valid HTML, and id attributes can not take more than one id (as you tried to do above, which is apparent by the spacing).

In CSS, ID's are referenced by a `#` symbol rather than a `.`.

Is this what you wanted?
http://fiddle.jshell.net/Shaz/Kwpj4/9/

Comment: yeah actually i noticed that too but wasn't sure if that was just a paste error or not.

Comment: Thanks, sorry I'm a copy-paster at the moment with css / html. I've updated the fiddle page, as I wanted the ratings to appear above the div. However I'm still getting the same issue where by the stars are appearing inside the div, and overlapping on the content as well (Much like the picture above)

Comment: Oh sorry I also noticed, I didn't put in the parent div. It seems to work in jsfiddle (Which is pretty cool). I'll play around some more

Comment: @steve: Take a look at the new link in the answer, tried to fix some of your css issues as well. :)